# Linq with dynamics "where parameter"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have this case:

I create an array from a list like this:

```
String[] parameters = stringParametersToSearch.Split(' ');
```

The number of parameters can vary from 1 to n and I have to search for objects that in the description field containing all the occurrences of **parameters**

```
List<LookUpObject> result = 
        components.Where(o => o.LongDescription.Contains(parameters[0])).ToList<LookUpObject>();
```

if the parameter is 1 do so, but if they had two or more?

Currently to resolve this situation, I use an IF in which I build the LINQ expression for cases up to five parameters (maximum of real cases).

**I can resolve this situation dynamically using LINQ ?**

Comment: Do you mean the description has to contain *any* of the parameters, or *all* of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You either want to use `Any` or `All`, depending on whether you want to find objects where all of the parameters match or any of them. So something like:

```
var result = components
    .Where(o => parameters.Any(p => o.LongDescription.Contains(p)))
    .ToList();
```

... but change `Any` to `All` if you need to.

It's always worth trying to describe a query in words, and then look at the words you've used. If you *use* the word "any" or "all" that's a good hint that you might want to use it in the query.

Having said that, given the example you posted (in a now-deleted comment), it's not clear that you really want to use string operations for this. If the long description is:

```
KW=50 CO2=69 KG=100
```

... then you'd end up matching on "G=100" or "KG=1" neither of which is what you really want, I suspect. You should probably parse the long description and parameters into name/value pairs, and look for *those* in the query.

Comment: Add a closing parenthesis  ".Contains(p)))"

Comment: Your answer is what I need. You can remove the "EDIT"

Comment: @daniele3004: No, I'll definitely leave it for anyone in a similar situation. Using `Contains` may be enough for your very specific context, but it's a bad idea *in general* at least.